# FF4 requires to clicks jquery why?

Tags: jquery, firefox4

Im really hoping someone will know the answer to this. Why does FF4 require 2 clicks to fire the resizeme?  Also while playing ive noticed that if i click a seperate image on the second click its grabbing the resize settings that should have been applied on the first click/image.  Its fine in FF3, safari, chrome, ie 7 and 8 for sure.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slideShow a").click(function() {
var imgTitle = $(this).children('img').attr('title'); // Find the image title
$("#thecap").html(' ' + imgTitle + ' ');
$("#lgImage").attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('rel'));
$( ".resizeme1" ).aeImageResize({ height: 372 });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try preventing the default *a* action

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slideShow a").click(function()
    {
        var $img = $(this).children('img'),
            imgTitle = $img.attr('title'); // Find the image title

        $('#thecap').
            text(' ' + imgTitle + ' ');

        $('#lgImage').
            attr('src', $img.attr('rel'));

        $('.resizeme1').
            aeImageResize({ 
                height: 372 
            });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: It's better to accept `event` into the callback, and use `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @user520300: Do a web search; there are loads of examples online.

Comment: if i put event.preventDefault() at the beginning of the function nothing at all happens, if i put it before the .resizeme1 the image changes but no resizing